# Время выполнения PHP превышает квоту

Tags: php, apache

Добрый день! Начинаю разбираться с PHP столкнулся с проблемой:

Скрипт обрабатывает Excel файл, зачастую его (файла) размер достаточно велик и на его обработку уходит большое количество времени. По этой причине скрипт не укладывается квоту времени выполнения apache (если я ничего не путаю). Увеличивать квоту не вариант, т.к. хостинг такой возможности не дает.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли возможность выполнения php-скрипта без замораживания страницы для пользователя, с которой скрипт был вызван? Или существует ли возможность каким либо образом обойти это ограничение по времени?

Спасибо!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-time-limit.php попробовать на хосте можно

Comment: Без замораживания страницы - только по crown или созданием фонового процесса. Обойти квоту можно только разбиением задачи на куски (slices) и запуском этих кусков из очереди. Поищите готовые решения в Сети, по словам php background, slices

Comment: Не crown, а cron. Опечатка, T9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да. Запускать скрипт в [режиме командной строки](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.commandline.php). При запуске значение [max_execution_time](http://php.net/manual/ru/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) по умолчанию равно 0 (неограниченно).

Как запускать, читайте — [Функции запуска программ](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.exec.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
ignore_user_abort(true); //Игнорируем обрыв связи с пользователем
set_time_limit(0); //Неограниченное время выполнения скрипта
```

Comment: Дайте пояснение к приведённому вами коду.